# Using for to change var name

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

In swift how to use this code:

```
    for i in 1...9 {

        model.xArray[i] = (z1.text as NSString).doubleValue

    }
```

To something like that:

```
for i in 1...9 {

    model.xArray[i] = (zi.text as NSString).doubleValue

}
```

I want to change the z1 var to z2, z3 etc like: model.xArray[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also possible is something like this:

```
for i in 1...9 {
  model.xArray[i] = (self.valueForKeyPath("z\(i).text") as! NSString).doubleValue
}
```

although i agree with **Bear with me** that you should use the array option...

Answer (score 2):

Add `z1`, `z2`, `z3`... to the array (`zArray`). Then you can do:

```
model.xArray[i] = (zArray[i].text as NSString).doubleValue
```

Comment: 'int' is not convertible to 'Range <Int>'

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Don't do that. Why do you want to programmatically change the variable that you are getting your value from? @BearWithMe s answer is the better solution. Use an array to store your different integer values.

If you're determined to fetch values from different variables then you can use valueForKeyPath as outlined by @AndréSlotta, but it's slow and error-prone.